# How to get posted data from WebBrowser

Tags: c#, post, browser

I want to get the posted data that the user send (fill, a form and click submit button),
it has to look something like this:

```
subcat_id=1601&title=sometitle&text_not=sometext
```

Comment: This is a very vague question. What is your objective? have you attempted to try this yourself, in which case can we see your code, or are you looking for a general guideline of how to implement this?

Comment: Well picture this:
i have webbrowser control in my application - ok?
Now the user fill some form and post data - ok?
the question is how to get the posted data????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answers is the event BeforeNavigate2